# How to get the Wifi password from a previously connected network?

Tags: wifi-password, xiaomi-mi-10t-pro

I have a Xiomi 10T Pro running Android 11. There is a WiFi whose password I want to know. My device is registered with that WiFi so I have no problem connecting to it BTW.

I am aware that I can choose to share my Wifi credentials from Settings. They are shared in the form of a QR code. That said, in my device I can share credentials for only those Wifi networks to which my device is connected to in **real time**.

This would not have been a problem except that the Wifi whose password I want to extract is hosted on a router that is located in an another country. So getting access to that real time Wifi is no longer feasible. My device is not rooted either.

So what can I do get the credentials for that Wifi without connecting to it?